# Cylces is casting shadows on the doughnut but not on the plane

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, shadows

Shadows are being cast on a plane in the Eevee, but not in Cylces. [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's starnge - when i open up your .blend file, i can see shadows on the plane both in EEVEE and in cycles. SO it seems not to be an issue with your scene but with your graphics card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your plane has overlapping faces, it creates *Z Fighting*, you need to select all in *Edit* mode and merge by distance